# Xcode 9.2 simulators crashing

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode9.2

Whenever I launch simulators on Xcode 9.2, the simualtors are crashing with multiple popups.

**Xcode version:** 9.2 (9C40b)

**Mac OS version:** 10.12.6 (16G1212)

Some of the error messages are as follows:

1. backboardd cannot be opened because of a problem.
2. SimultorBridge cannot be opened because of a problem.
3. SpringBoard cannot be opened because of a problem.

**Crash report for SimultorBridge is as follows:**

```
Process:               SimulatorBridge [4361]

Path:                /Users/USER/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/Platforms/iphoneos/usr/libexec/SimulatorBridge

Identifier:            SimulatorBridge

Version:               835.5 (835.5)

Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)

Parent Process:        launchd_sim [4313]

Responsible:           SimulatorBridge [4361]

User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-02-21 12:36:15.729 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1212)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        6844F1F8-F647-09F6-8FB0-A7B9C14F843B


Time Awake Since Boot: 10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Octane_Nimesh/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Users/Octane_Nimesh/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/Octane_Nimesh/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/CoreAnalytics
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
  Reason: image not found
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on xcode 9.2. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I was using the Xcode 9.2 BETA version. After installing the final release version, the issue was resolved. Please try to reinstall Xcode as this issues might occur because of the corrupted simulator files.

Comment: Right. So, for me too the issue vanished after reinstalling Xcode. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall Xcode as this issues might occur because of the corrupted simulator files.